# Square pattern java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Create void method that will put on screen square with patern like that :

```
  xoxo  
  xoxo   
  xoxo   
  xoxo
```

First argument of the method will define amount of characters used to create a square side, second which character is first.

This is my solution but im wondering if i can do it with less code.

```
static void square(char a, int b) {
 if (a == 'x') {
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {

            int sum = 0;
            do {


                System.out.print("x");
                sum++;
                if (sum == b)
                    break;
                System.out.print("o");
                sum++;

            }
            while (sum != b);

            System.out.println();
        }

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {

            int sum = 0;
            do {


                System.out.print("o");
                sum++;
                if (sum == b)
                    break;
                System.out.print("x");
                sum++;

            }
            while (sum != b);

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

How to make pattern to look like

```
xoxox
oxoxo
xoxox
oxoxo
xoxox
```

And how to make this using only for loops or arrays.

Comment: You can, but you'd need to define the character order (ie, do you want `xo` or `ox`)

Comment: *Note*: Working code questions should go on [*code review*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), the question is still a bit broad for that site. So is for a solution or code that isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(n^2) loop and constant O(k) space. Start from 0 and just keep alternating the characters till you reach the end (b^2).

```
char oth = (a == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';
for (int i = 0; i < (b * b); i++) {
    System.out.print(i % 2 == 0 ? a : oth);
    if ((i + 1) % b == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

O(n) loop and O(n) space. Construct the two pattern rows to print and alternate them.

```
char oth = (a == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';
String x = (a == 'x') ? "xo" : "ox";

// Construct the two repeating patterns which will alternate
String first = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(b / 2, x));
String second = first;
if (b % 2 == 1) {
    second = new StringBuilder(first).reverse().toString();
    first += a;
    second += oth;
}
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    System.out.println(i % 2 == 0 ? first : second);
}
```

See output here: https://ideone.com/E3bVFK

Answer (score 0):

Have fun

```
public static void square(int side, char order){
    char x = (order=='x')?'x':'o';
    char o = (order=='x')?'o':'x';
    for ( int i = 0; i < side; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < side; j++ )
            System.out.print((j%2==0)?x:o);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output would be exactly what you were asking for.